# Porque al usar pointers para una variable tipo char no obtengo la direccion fisica en memoria de la variable?

Tags: c++, punteros

soy novato en C++ y estoy haciendo el curso de c++ emitido por Udacity. En la sesion de pointers estoy aprendiendo a acceder a las direcciones fisica donde se almacenan las variables pero me encuentro con la peculiaridad que la intentar imprimir la direccion fisica de una variable tipo char, esta no se imprime. Que puede estas sucediendo?. Creo que es necesario decir que estoy utilizando el editor ofrecido por la plataforma (https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud999/lessons/7761613e-1edd-4ccc-bb67-6faeeac7d97e/concepts/ed81d654-601d-4ea5-9540-b63acefb272e)

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
/*For this program print for each variable
**print the value of the variable, 
**then print the address where it is stored. 
*/
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int main()
{
    int givenInt;
    float givenFloat;
    double givenDouble ;
    std::string givenString;
    char givenChar;
    std::cin>>givenInt;
    std::cin>>givenDouble;
    std::cin>>givenFloat;
    std::cin>>givenChar;
    std::getline(std::cin,givenString);
    std::cout<<"The value for givenInt is: "<<givenInt<<" and its address is "<<&givenInt<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"The value for givenDouble is: "<<givenDouble<<" and its address is "<<&givenDouble<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"The value for givenFloat is: "<<givenFloat<<" and its address is "<<&givenFloat<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"The value for givenChar is: "<<givenChar<<" and its address is "<<&givenChar<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"The value for givenString is: "<<givenString<<" and its address is "<<&givenString<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

My output es el siguiente:

```
The value for givenInt is: 32 and its address is 0x7fffefdd8418
The value for givenDouble is: 64.212 and its address is 0x7fffefdd8428
The value for givenFloat is: 4.76545 and its address is 0x7fffefdd841c
The value for givenChar is: a and its address is a 
The value for givenString is:  and its address is 0x7fffefdd8420
```

Como ven, no se imprime la direccion para la variable tipo char. Sin embargo, si añado `(void *)` antes del pointer de la variable char, funciona!! Que hace exactamente este segmento? (en la solucion del ejercicio estaba esta parte pero explican que hace).

```
std::cout<<"The value for givenChar is: "<<givenChar<<" and its address is "<<(void *)&givenChar<<"\n";
```

el output es:

```
The value for givenChar is: a and its address is 0x7ffe4da97887
```

Answer (score 7):

Tu código es equivalente a este:

```
char givenChar = 'a';
char* ptr = &givenChar;
std::cout << ptr;
```

Si echamos un vistazo a las [sobrecargas del operador de inserción](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator-free/) para el objeto `cout`, que es de tipo `ostream`, encontramos lo siguiente:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const char* s);
```

Esta sobrecarga se usa para imprimir cadenas de caracteres:

```
std::cout << "Hola a todo el mundo";
```

Y el compilador no tiene forma de saber que tu aquí lo que pretendes es sacar la dirección de memoria del puntero.

Pero, ¿Por qué en los otros casos funciona correctamente? Básicamente porque no hay una sobrecarga específica para un puntero de tipo `int`, ni `float`, ni `double`, ... en estos casos el programa ejecuta la [siguiente sobrecarga](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/):

```
ostream& operator<< (void* val);
```

Ya que un puntero de tipo `void` es considerado como un puntero genérico.

Para que tu programa funcione como esperas lo único que has de hacer es forzar tu puntero a `char` para que pase como puntero a `void`:

```
std::cout << "The value for givenChar is: "
          << givenChar
          << " and its address is "
          << static_cast<void*>(&givenChar) // <<--- Conversión a void*
          <<"\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

La dirección de un carácter tiene tipo `char *`, que *casualmente* es el mismo tipo que los literales de texto, por lo tanto te lo imprime como texto y te muestra `a`.

Conviértelo a puntero a `void`:

```
std::cout
    << "The value for givenChar is: " << givenChar
    << " and its address is " << reinterpret_cast<void *>(&givenChar)
    << "\n";
```